# SQL Sum of column based on other Column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access-2007

Unfortunately My tables will be poor and I have no idea how to fix that. Essentially I have this table and I want to sum all the values on the right based on one value on the left. This is sample data but it will be 400+ records in the database. So if the numbers on the left are IDs for customers, and the numbers on the right are products purchased, how do I get a summary of products purchased per customer?

```
1   4
1   2
2   3
3   2
2   4
1   1
3   2
1   3
```

The final result would need to look like this:

```
1   10
2   7
3   4
```

Comment: This is a basic `group by` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
user_table.userID,
SUM(user_table.prodcut_purchase)
FROM
user_table
GROUP BY
user_table.userID
```

Comment: Works Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Sorry they don't let you select an answer right away and I had to leave but there you go!